# Recognising variables while assigning a function to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, closures

In my jQuery scripts, when the user closes a menu with an animation, I have to call a function after the closing animation is finished. I want to assign this function dynamically by calling a function openStrip() with a parameter. My code looks like:

```
var FUNCTION_JUST_AFTER_MENU_CLOSE = function(){};
function openStrip(stripId){
      FUNCTION_JUST_AFTER_MENU_CLOSE = function(){
          createStrip(stripId);
      });
}
```

if I call openStrip("aStripId"), I expect FUNCTION_JUST_AFTER_MENU_CLOSE to be:

```
// #1    
function(){
    createStrip("aStripId");
}
```

whereas my current code gives:

```
//#2
function(){
    createStrip(stripId);
}
```

i.e, the parameter passed to the function openStrip() is lost while assigning the function() to the variable FUNCTION_JUST_AFTER_MENU_CLOSE.

How can I avoid this.

EDIT: I discovered that my code is actually working. The problem was elsewhere. I got confused because when I looked at Chrome's debugger, it was showing me the function definition as is (#2 in above). But when it actually went down executing that function later in the code, it did evaluate the values of the passed argument, and endedup executing #1.

Thanks for the answer though. I am marking it correct because that is perhaps a better way of assigning the function.

Comment: Closures a created by keeping the variable `stripId` *in the scope*, not by replacing every occurrence of it in the code. The function body is not altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to return a function, from `openStrip` like this

```
function openStrip(stripId) {
    return function() {
        createStrip(stripId);
    };
}
```

For example,

```
function openStrip(stripId) {
    return function() {
        console.log(stripId);
    };
}

openStrip("aStripId")();
# aStripId
openStrip("bStripId")();
# bStripId
```

You can even assign the function objects returned to different variables and use them later on

```
var aStrip = openStrip("aStripId");
aStrip();
# aStripId
aStrip();
# aStripId
```